# how to hide files from package explorer

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Hi all
I am developing a plugin where i m creating project through my own wizard.
I have used javaElementFilters to hide my file named device-configs.xml.
It only works with eclipse helios sdk versions.

Can anyone suggest me better way to hide file?
Or other extension point that can work in all eclipse versions of 3.6 & also in MyEclipse also?

Answer (score 14):

1. Make sure that you have Package Explorer opened
2. Select View Menu on the top of the Package Explorer view
   [image: Package Explorer View Menu]
3. Select filters
   [image: Filters]
4. Enter your pattern and click OK

[image: Filename pattern]

Files should be hidden.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Resource Filters for some reason did not work.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the project, then go Properties, then Resource > Resource Filters and add a exclude filter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found another way to hide the file which works for me.

Comment: I just have to use the api of IFile to hide the file from eclipse. This api will only hide the file in eclipse but it wont affect the properties of file in file system.

Answer (score 1):

The javaElementFilters work only in the Views supplied by JDT and it should work in all the versions. What do you mean by "only works with eclipse helios sdk versions"?

Comment: The javaelementfilter didnt work in the eclipse 3.6 JavaEE SR1 version. Still i have found another way to hide the file. But this method will hide it from eclipse as whole. The file will not be visible in any of the views of eclipse.