# Does Eclipse have equivalent of .svnignore/.cvsignore for Project Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working with a project that creates dozens of temporary files in my project root directory. These files have no bearing on my coding but clutter the Project Explorer tree, making it harder to find actually important files.

Does Eclipse have any kind of feature or plugin to cause Project Explorer to ignore certain files (similar to how you can use .svnignore to tell Subversion to ignore files)?

Comment: Maybe using filters ? see [hide files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218721/how-to-hide-files-from-package-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-48b.htm) help you should follow the steps bellow:

1. On the toolbar for the Project Explorer, click the Menu button  to
   open the drop-down menu of display options.
2. Select Customize View..,.
3. In the dialog box that opens, select the Filters tab and
   then select the checkboxes for the types of files that you want to
   hide.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Btw, for anyone reading, the 'menu' button is the teeny-tiny dropdown arrow in the top right of the Project Explorer pane that you would never think of clicking on!