# Eclipse hiding project packages for easy navigation in package explorer

Tags: eclipse, syntax, ide, settings

Is there a way in eclipse's package explorer to hide certain packages that you are likely not going to open in a long time?

i.e

```
com.proj.game.server.vars
com.proj.game.apple
com.proj.game.pear
com.proj.game.banana
com.proj.game.zvariable.users
```

I know that eclipse's package explorer allows shot-forming the name, i.e you can rename (cosmetic) com.proj to "cpj" so that it will show as:

```
cpj.game.server.vars
cpj.game.apple
cpj.game.pear
cpj.game.banana
cpj.game.zvariable.users
```

But is there a way that I can for example hide (cosmetic) certain packages?

I want my explorer to show as:

```
cpj.game.server.vars
...
cpj.game.zvariable.users
```

(Hide fruits)

Edit:

Looking at this: [how to hide files from package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218721/how-to-hide-files-from-package-explorer)

What value should I input in the "your pattern here" box to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the full package name in the "your pattern here" text box without qoutes. If you want multiple packages to hide, separate them with comma. That's it.